# significance of $ and "" in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am learning MongoDB. Getting confused on usage of "$"
I have collection as below schema:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  "name": "test",
  "city": "gr",
  "sector": "IT",
  "salary":1000
}
```

I find below output on executing below query:

```
 Query                                 Result

db.user.find({salary:2000});           Works
db.user.find({$salary:2000});          does not work(unknown top level operator: $salary)
db.user.aggregate({$group:{_id:null,avg:{$avg:"$salary"}}}); Works
db.user.aggregate({$group:{_id:null,avg:{$avg:$salary}}});    does not work($salary is not defined)
db.user.aggregate({$group:{_id:null,avg:{$avg:"salary"}}});   gives wrong output.
```

Can anyone please explain,what is the syntactical significance of "" and $ in mongoDB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi lets look at these queries

```
1- db.user.find({salary:2000});          
2- db.user.find({$salary:2000});
```

Take a look at this for [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/). 
According to this find takes {field: value}, your first query works because salary is valid field.
Your second query doesn't work becuase there is no field $salary

```
3- db.user.aggregate({$group:{_id:null,avg:{$avg:"$salary"}}});
4- db.user.aggregate({$group:{_id:null,avg:{$avg:$salary}}});   
5- db.user.aggregate({$group:{_id:null,avg:{$avg:"salary"}}});
```

For aggregation, lets take a look at this [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/).
Here it says that $avg takes {$avg: expression}. So you are actually keeping expression over there not a field.

Now take a look at this for [expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions).
Expression can be field paths and system variables, literals, expression objects, and expression operators.

Query numbers 3,4,5 aren't expression objects or expression operators. So lets eliminate these options.

Now lets take a look at [$literal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#agg-quick-ref-literals).
It states that literals can be of any type, however MongoDB parses literals that start with a dollar sign as a path to a field.

Finally take a look at [Field Path and System variables](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#agg-quick-ref-field-paths).
It states "To specify a field path, use a string that prefixes with a dollar sign $ ... For example, "$user" to specify the field path for the user field or "$user.name" to specify the field path to "user.name" field."

That means you are specifying $salary as path to the field in $avg:"$salary" and query number 3 works.

Query number 4 doesn't work because $salary is an invalid expression.

This should explain the significance of ""

Query number 5 is not working because again it doesn't find any field to average on. Though it works because its a valid query it simply returns null.
You could have had

```
db.user.aggregate({$group:{_id:null,avg:{$avg:"some_non_existent_field"}}});
```

And the query will still run fine but you will get null for your results.
I hope this helps, this was a lot of fun to gather.